# Select only <tr> with some class before a button using jquery

Tags: jquery

i have this html markup and i want to select some rows using jQuery.

When pressing the button with class 'cerrar' i want to select the **3 tr with class 'hidden' before the same button**

```
 <tr class='main'>
            <td class='table-sub-title'> 
                Test
            </td>
            <td class='table-sub-title'>
                Test
            </td>
            <td class='table-sub-title'>
                Test
            </td>
            <td class='table-sub-title'>
                Test
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='hidden'> <!-- ********* Select this <tr> ********* -->
            <td class='noborder'>
                Test
            </td>
            <td class='noborder'>
                Test
            </td>
            <td class='noborder'>
                Test
            </td>
            <td class='noborder'>
                Test
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='hidden'> <!-- ********* Select this <tr> ********* -->
            <td class='noborder'>
                Test
            </td>
            <td class='noborder'>
                Test
            </td>
            <td class='noborder'>
                Test
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='hidden'> <!-- ********* Select this <tr> ********* -->
            <td class='noborder'>
                Test
            </td>
            <td class='noborder'>
                Test
            </td>
            <td class='noborder'>
            </td>
            <td class='noborder'>
                <input type='button' name='Cancelar' value='Cancelar' class='cerrar' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='main'>...
    <!-- Repeat -->
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just do like this:

```
$('.cerrar').click(function(){

    // Get all the tr's with hidden class before button
    var TRs = $(this).closest('tr').prevUntil("tr.main").andSelf();

});
```

Comment: Thanks for ur quick reply, but i want to select the 3 tr with class 'hidden' before the button.

Comment: That will select all `tr.hidden`, not just the ones prior to the button.  What if there are more after it?

Comment: So close! from <tr class='main'> to the <tr> before the next <tr class='main'> represent one item, if there are more items i want to select the 3 <tr class='hidden'> inside the item

Comment: Glad you got the solution :)